# How should I configure excel column mapping to a class property in C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I'm building an importation from an Excel file. I want to store the data into my class.
I want to avoid hardcoding the column name into my code, because the user change them frequently. I was thinking about a config file that I could map a column name to a class property.

```
<excelFileSetting filePath="path\to\my\file.xlsx"> 
    <columnMappings>
        <add columnName="Excel Col Name" classProperty="MyNamespace.MyClass.MyProperty" />
    </columnMappings>
</excelFileSetting>
```

I know how to build the config section and how to read the values.

The question is when I'm reading the Excel file, how can I map a cell value to a property ?
I put the excel file content into a datatable.
Right now, i'm doing this to create my object:

```
var myClass = new MyClass{
    MyProperty = dataRow["Excel Col Name"].ToString() 
}
```

Do you have any ideas on how I could acheive the mapping ?
Or maybe I'm not going in the right direction and I should use another method ?

I look at the nuget LinqToExcel, but the excel file I'm working with is not well formatted and I cannot change the format.

Comment: If the column names are the only thing that changes, then map the properties by column index: `MyProperty = dataRow[0].ToString()`

Comment: @MetroSmurf good point. I knew I was thinking for something too complex ! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @MetroSurf suggested, I use column index insted of string based mapping.
I was thinking of something too complex.

Here is what I did in my app.config :

```
<ReportConfig 
    filePath="C:\temp\myFile.xslm"
    sheetToRead="MASTER"
    projectNameColumnNumber="4"
    customerNameColumnNumber="5"
    startDateColumnNumber="18"
    plannedDateColumnNumber="19">
  </ReportConfig>
```

And then, when I assign in my class I can do :

```
var reportRow = new ReportRow{ 
    ProjectName = dataRow[reportConfig.ProjectNameColumnNumber].ToString()
}
```

For the full detail on how to implement custom configuration section in the app.config, I suggest reading this : https://ivankahl.com/creating-custom-configuration-sections-in-app-config/